# Finding number of subarrays whose sum equals `k`

Tags: java, algorithm

We would be given an array of integers and a value `k`.  We need to find the total number of sub-arrays whose sum equals `k`.

I found some interesting code online (on Leetcode) which is as follows:

```
public class Solution {
    public int subarraySum(int[] nums, int k) {
        int sum = 0, result = 0;
        Map<Integer, Integer> preSum = new HashMap<>();
        preSum.put(0, 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            sum += nums[i];
            if (preSum.containsKey(sum - k)) {
                result += preSum.get(sum - k);
            }
            preSum.put(sum, preSum.getOrDefault(sum, 0) + 1);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

To understand it, I walked through some specific examples like `[1,1,1,1,1]` with `k=3` and `[1,2,3,0,3,2,6]` with `k=6`.  While the code works perfectly in both the cases, I fail to follow how it actually computes the output.

### I have two specific points of confusion:

1) Why does the code continuously add the values in the array, without ever zeroing it out?  For example, in case of `[1,1,1,1,1]` with `k=3`, once `sum=3`, don't we need to reset `sum` to zero? Doesn't not resetting `sum` interfere with finding later subarrays?

2) Shouldn't we simply do `result++` when we find a subarray of sum `k`? Why do we add `preSum.get(sum-k)` instead?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Let's handle your first point of confusion first:

The reason the code keeps summing the array and doesn't reset `sum` is because we are saving the sum in `preSum` (previous sums) as we go. Then, any time we get to a point where `sum-k` is a previous sum (say at index `i`), we know that the sum *between* index `i` and our current index is exactly `k`.

For example, in the image below with `i=2`, and our current index equal to `4`, we can see that since `9`, the sum at our current index, minus `3`, the sum at index `i`, is `6`, the sum between indexes `2` and `4` (inclusive) is `6`.

[image: Example Image]

Another way to think about this is to see that discarding `[1,2]` from the array (at our current index of `4`) gives us a subarray of sum `6`, for similar reasons as above (see image for details).

Using this method of thinking, we can say we want to discard from the front of the array until we are left with a subarray of sum `k`. We could do this by saying, for each index, "discard just `1`, then discard `1+2`, then discard `1+2+3`, etc" (these numbers are from our example)  until we found a subarray of sum `k` (`k=6` in our example).

That gives a perfectly valid solution, but notice we would be doing this at every index of our array, and thus summing the same numbers over and over. A way to save computation would be to save these sums for later use. Even better, we already sum these same numbers to get our current `sum`, so we can just save that total as we go.

To find a subarray, we can just look through our saved sums, subtracting them and testing if what we are left with is `k`. It is a bit annoying to have to subtract every saved sum, so we can use the [commutativity of subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) to see that if `sum-x=k` is true, `sum-k=x` is also true. This way we can just see if `x` is a saved sum, and, if it is, know we have found a subarray of size `k`. A hash map makes this lookup efficient.

### Now for your second point of confusion:

Most of the time you are right, upon finding an appropriate subarray we could just do `result++`. Almost always, the values in `preSum` will be `1`, so `result+=preSum.get(sum-k)` will be equivalent to `result+=1`, or `result++`.

The only time it isn't is when `preSum.put` is called on a `sum` that has been reached before. How can we get back to a `sum` we already had? The only way is with either negative numbers, which cancel out previous numbers, or with zero, which doesn't affect the sum at all.

Basically, we get back to a previous `sum` when a subarray's sum is equal to 0. Two examples of such subarrays are `[2,-2]` or the trivial `[0]`. With such a subarray, when we find a later, adjoining subarray with sum `k`, we need to add more than `1` to `result` as we have found more than one new subarray, one with the zero-sum subarray (`sum=k+0`) and one without it (`sum=k`).

This is the reason for that `+1` in the `preSum.put` as well. Every time we reach the same `sum` again, we have found *another* zero-sum subarray. With two zero-sum subarrays, finding a new adjoining subarray with `sum=k` actually gives 3 subarrays: the new subarray (`sum=k`), the new subarray plus the first zero-sum (`sum=k+0`), and the original with both zero-sums (`sum=k+0+0`). This logic holds for higher numbers of zero-sum subarrays as well.

Comment: "Basically, we get back to a previous sum when a subarray's sum is equal to 0. " .I am not getting above example can you explain it with another example. thanks.

Comment: If the subarray equals 0, it contributes nothing to the sum, so the sum is the same with or without it, giving two options to achieve the same sum.

Comment: Explanation for 2nd point is confusing. The question says why do *+ preSum.get(sum-k)* instead of *result++*?

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone What is confusing? We can't use `result++` as with zero-sum subarrays, a new entry can lead to the discovery of multiple new subarrays. e.g. consider `k=6` with `[1,2,3,0,3]` (3 subarrays) vs `[1,2,3,0,3,3]` (5 subarrays). When we find the extra 3, it leads to the discovery of *2* new subarrays of sum 6 ([3,3] and [0,3,3]); `result++` would only increment by 1.

Comment: Ah ok now that clear. Another scenario would be [1,- 2,3] and [  3,-4,1, 1,-2,3] . Where [3,-4,1, . . .] producing 0 but [ 3,-4,1, 1,-2,3]  will also taken coz it sums to 2.